# Assigning new QgsRasterBlock object to QgsRasterDataProvider object?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

Next code, read and print original and modified raster pixels values by using a **QgsRasterBlock** object ('block' method of **QgsRasterDataProvider**). The objective is to obtain a new raster with the new block values. However, these new values are not overwritten in the provider; as it can be observed at next image (with the help of Value Tool plugin).

[image]

Complete code is:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

extent = provider.extent()

rows = layer.height()
cols = layer.width()

xsize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
ysize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

print rows, cols

block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)

print "original block"

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        print block.value(i,j)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if block.value(i,j) == 4:
            block.setValue(i, j, 25)

print "modified block"

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        print block.value(i,j)

pipe = QgsRasterPipe()

pipe.set(provider.clone())

rasterWriter = QgsRasterFileWriter("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test_write.tif")

xSize = provider.xSize()
ySize = provider.ySize()

CRS = layer.crs()

error = rasterWriter.writeRaster(pipe, xSize, ySize, provider.extent(), CRS)

if error == QgsRasterFileWriter.NoError:
    print "Raster was saved successfully!"

else:
    print "Raster was not saved!"
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, it can be corroborated that block object was modified as expected.

```
3 3
original block
10.0
2.0
2.0
10.0
3.0
2.0
8.0
4.0
4.0
modified block
10.0
2.0
2.0
10.0
3.0
2.0
8.0
25.0
25.0
Raster was saved successfully!
```

When I try to create a new instance of **QgsRasterDataProvider**, I got that "cannot be instantiated".

```
TypeError: qgis._core.QgsRasterDataProvider represents a C++ abstract class
and cannot be instantiated
```

How can I overwrite correctly the new block values in the original (or a new) provider?

Answer (score 2):

I found out a solution to the problem of overwrite block values in the original provider. It is necessary to use two additional **QgsRasterDataProvider** methods: 'setEditable' and 'writeBlock'. However, following code (with only two additional lines including above methods) modify original raster as expected resulting raster and written raster has the values of original raster.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

extent = provider.extent()

rows = layer.height()
cols = layer.width()

xsize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
ysize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

print (rows, cols)

block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)
provider.setEditable(True)

print ("original block")

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        print (block.value(i,j))

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if block.value(i,j) == 4:
            block.setValue(i, j, 25)

print ("modified block")

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        print (block.value(i,j))

provider.writeBlock(block, 1)

pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider.clone())

rasterWriter = QgsRasterFileWriter("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test_write.tif")

xSize = provider.xSize()
ySize = provider.ySize()

CRS = layer.crs()

error = rasterWriter.writeRaster(pipe, xSize, ySize, provider.extent(), CRS)

if error == QgsRasterFileWriter.NoError:
    print ("Raster was saved successfully!")

else:
    print ("Raster was not saved!")
```

In following image, with the help of **Value Tool Plugin**, it can be observed that they were swapped:

[image]

On the other hand, if this line:

```
pipe.set(provider.clone())
```

is changed to:

```
pipe.set(provider)
```

resulting raster is gotten as expected but issue in original raster persist: their values are the same of resulting raster.