# Preserving provider of original raster layer when it is modified for another resulting raster layer?

Tags: pyqgis, python-3

A while ago, I asked for a method to assign new **QgsRasterBlock** objects to a **QgsRasterDataProvider** objects at [Assign new QgsRasterBlock object to a QgsRasterDataProvider object](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206784). The reason was for using only **PyQGIS** methods to manipulate raster layers avoiding **GDAL/OGR** python module. Recently, I found out a potential solution, posted as an [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206784/assign-new-qgsrasterblock-object-to-a-qgsrasterdataprovider-object/334269#334269); however original provider is not preserved in original raster.

I found out that **QgsRasterDataProvider** missing methods in my first post were 'setEditable' and 'writeBlock'. I also found out, for avoiding QGIS crashing during each test, it is necessary to add as last line `provider = None`.

Following simplified version of original code looks as follow:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

extent = provider.extent()

rows = layer.height()
cols = layer.width()

xsize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
ysize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)
provider.setEditable(True)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if block.value(i,j) == 4:
            block.setValue(i, j, 25)

provider.writeBlock(block, 1)

pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider)

rasterWriter = QgsRasterFileWriter("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test_write.tif")

xSize = provider.xSize()
ySize = provider.ySize()

CRS = layer.crs()

error = rasterWriter.writeRaster(pipe, xSize, ySize, provider.extent(), CRS)

if error == QgsRasterFileWriter.NoError:
    print ("Raster was saved successfully!")

else:
    print ("Raster was not saved!")

provider = None
```

After running above code in Python Console of QGIS, with a copy of **test_sample**, this one looks identical to original; as it can be observed in following image:

[image]

However, Value  Tool Plugin corroborates that it effectively changed:

[image]

When I load **test_write** resulting layer and **test_sample_copy** (from hard disk), both layers look as expected (corroborated again by Value Tool Plugin).

[image]

However, after erasing **test_write** and **test_sample_copy** and reloading both layers again, it was corroborated that **test_sample_copy** effectively and unexpectedly changed.

[image]

So, there is something wrong in the way I created the provider for resulting layer because modify unexpectedly the provider of original raster layer.

How can the provider of original raster layer be preserved when it is modified for another raster layer?